# Why can't Django sites be embedded inside another HTML(iframe)?

Tags: python, html, django, iframe

I tried  embedding a django form in another html page but it does not work. I tried my other django sites. But nothing works. Also tested for some other sites. Is django restricted to be used in iframe? How to make it work?
form needed to be embedded [Programming competition form](http://form.classof20.cf/Programming_Competition/)

Template:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <b>{{form.as_p}}</b>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit" />
</form>
```

Try to embedded as:

```
<html>
<iframe frameborder="1" src="http://form.classof20.cf/Programming_Competition/"></iframe>
</html>
```

It give a border and nothing inside.

Comment: Maybe the other site doesn't want to be embedded. If it's not your site, you have no control over how it behaves.

Comment: Its my site and I want it to be embedded. how can I do so?

Comment: You should show what code you've created that's giving you trouble. We can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: I dont know what code to show here, as non django sites are embedded. do you want to view the template page code?

Comment: Give us enough to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's best to include that in the body of the question. External resources are really frowned upon since not everyone is prepared to click some random link.

Comment: embedding has nothing to do with django ... its just html ...

Comment: Actually @tadman, the OP gave the URL and HTML code to reproduce, a quick look at webkit error console showed the issue, if anybody downvoted for that reason they might want to reconsider ;)

Comment: Actually @Joran Beasley, this has to do with Django, because this is caused by Django clickjacking protection, if anybody downvoted for that reason they might want to reconsider ;)

Comment: @jpic URLs change, servers break, and someone might stumble on this problem tomorrow or two years from now. If the question includes code that's no longer there, this question becomes worthless, so it's best to have it self-contained.

Comment: @tadman just make an empty django project, add his view code, use his HTML to embed it: you'll get the same error. That said, directly using the URL did make it easier to answer the question, this working URL is just a bonus point for the OP. But I do get your point, and will think about it next time I see a question that's not self contained (which is not the case here, as demonstrated).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the error in webkit inspector after trying to load your HTML:

```
Refused to display 'http://form.classof20.cf/Programming_Competition/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

And indeed, here's a dump of the response headers by curl:

```
$ curl -I http://form.classof20.cf/Programming_Competition/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 19:44:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 765
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=UJZltdTzJMe6961QMNRSgZ7vKWa1vUEf2lEB8lmaaZXgROf1zyALsuwsKpvtcby6; expires=Wed, 05-Sep-2018 19:44:16 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

So, where does it come from ? It comes from [Django clickjacking protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/clickjacking/).

Solution 0: make sure your django response [allows your other site in X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), ie:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://your-other-site-which-embeds/
```

Solution 1: exempt your form view from clickjacking protection:

> When using the middleware there may be some views where you do not
>   want the X-Frame-Options header set. For those cases, you can use a
>   view decorator that tells the middleware not to set the header:
>
> ```
> from django.http import HttpResponse
> from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
>
> @xframe_options_exempt
> def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
>     return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
> ```

Comment: Thank you! It works, and this has to do with Django.. :)