# django getting error :Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: django

i have set X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

but still
getting error :Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Django sites be embedded inside another HTML(iframe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080433/why-cant-django-sites-be-embedded-inside-another-htmliframe)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no it does not , i tried lots of ways but , it always shows deny in error message and network tab

Comment: Did you use the `xframe_options_exempt` decorator as described there? [Edit] your question and show the view for the page which you are trying to put in an iframe, did you use the decorator on it?

Comment: well its not a view , it's a pdf url , which i need to show in iframe

Comment: or is there any way which i can use to show documents , images etc , without exposing there url .

Comment: ohh it is working but in my machine it works only in private mode of chrome